# Why in Laravel 5.8 Observer does not work

Tags: laravel, observers, laravel-5.8

Actually made observer by command `php artisan make:observer ProfileObserver --model=Profile`

In AppServiceProvider.php:-

```
    public function boot(Request $request) {
        Profile::observe(ProfileObserver::class);       
    }
```

In ProfileObserver.php:-

```
    public function updating(Profile $profile) {
        die('here');
    }
```

and actually i have model **Profile**
Why observer not work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
first i used

```
Profile::where('id', $id)->update($inputs);
```

and that's not triggered any action.
Replaced with

```
Profile::find($id)->update($inputs);
```